# How to build a search page with multiple search fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have a search page which has 8 searching criteria.In Javascript I want build a search (just a function since i can write the queries) with multiple search combinations as below,
My search fields are, A,B,C,D,E,F,G&H
Currently i'm trying to build like below,

```
if (a != "" && b == "" && c == "" && d == "" && e == "" && f == "" && g == "" && h == "") { 
  // my code queries for 'a'
} else if (a != "" && b != "" && c == "" && d == "" && e == "" && f == "" && g == "" && h == "") { 
  // my code queries for both 'a' & 'b'
}
```

So likewise I have to write a lot of combinations. Is there a simple way or a loop to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. To work out the filtering logic we need to see the data set you're working with, and also know how the filtering should work, ie. is it inclusive, exclusive etc

Comment: Can you just say `if (a != "") { code for a }` and then similar for the others, for a total of 8 `if` statements each dealing with their own variable only, and concatenate the results into a single query statement at the end?

Comment: @nnnnnn thats ho currently i have done it but i have to validate each variable, so there comes more than 100 of combinations.

Comment: That's *not* how you've currently done it. I suggested a total of only 8 `if` statements. (Which certainly could work in some situations, but I'm not sure about yours because question doesn't have enough detail.)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the datatable has the columns such as A-H so in the search page user might only enter the value for A and another user might enter values of F , H & E vice versa.. So i need a simplest solution for this.
Thank you.

Comment: @nnnnnn 
in the search page user might only enter the value for A and another user might enter values of F , H & E vice versa.. so having only 8 if statements will ot cater i think.. elaborate further if iam wrongly understood,
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I understood that any given query could include any combination of any number of the variables. If the user enters multiple values in F, G, and H, what effect does that have on the query you are trying to produce? If you can separately add criteria for F in one `if` statement, then append criteria for G in another `if` statement, etc. (note i didn't say to use any `else` statements) then you would only need one `if` per variable.

Comment: @nnnnnn
i will check and update it .
Thank you

Comment: @nnnnnn ,
sorry for the delayed reply, i could do that it works fine, but the problem is, i have a html table presenting the results, so when i execute like that its not cobining both the input values but instead it shows two seperate table results i mean the results are not combined..

Answer (score 1):

You could store the criterions in an array and then filter this array to get rid of the blank values.

```
criterions = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h];
citerions = criterions.filter(
  function(value){
    return value != "";
  },
  criterions
);
```

Then you can loop through the criterions array to build your search

Comment: But this way cant know which criteria is empty?

Comment: If you want to know the empty criterions, you can do another filter where you test for blank values and store it in another array

Comment: @SébastienMaloron
Thank you, but if i want to assign the values which are inside criterions, into variables how could i do that, Let say criterions has c & d inside it and how would i create variables for both c & d
Thank you very much.

Comment: @SébastienMaloron ,
Would appreciate if you can give me a feedback,

Answer (score 0):

Store searching criteria to array object containing criteria and value. We can filter out not empty object, and then query for its key.

```
let data = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: ''}, {d: ''}];
data = data.filter((d)=>Object.values(d)[0]); [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
data = data.map((d)=>Object.keys(d)[0]); // ['a', 'b']
// queries for data, ['a', 'b']
```